# MySQL: Unique if column = x

Tags: mysql, unique

Let's say a table has 3 columns can I then make it so that the mix between column 1 & 2 is  unique if (and only if) column 3 is equal to x?

That would make this work:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|     A     |        B       |           C           |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     1     |        2       |           x           |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     2     |        1       |           x           |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     0     |        0       |           y           |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     0     |        0       |           y           |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

And this wouldn't:

```
|     A     |        B       |           C           |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     2     |        2       |           x           |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     2     |        2       |           x           |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     0     |        0       |           y           |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     0     |        0       |           y           |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `| 0 | 0 | y ` is not unique in the first set?! And how you would like to select the unique value for column `C` for each grouped value `A, B`? `MIN`, `MAX`, .. etx

Comment: No that's what I want. If C is y then the mix between A & B shouldn't be unique. If it is x then A & B should be unique.

Comment: So you want the combination `A`, `B` values have to be unique if the `C` column = 'x'? i.e. `UNIQUE KEY (A, B) only if C = 'x'` right? If so edit your question with these details.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal That is correct. The combination A & B can't be the same if C = x twice but can if C = y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a trigger:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER special_unique_test BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.C = 'x' AND EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE A = NEW.A AND B = NEW.B AND C = 'x'
) THEN
  CALL raise_error;
END IF;;

DELIMITER ;
```

I'd recommend maintaining an index on `(A, B, C)` to keep this reasonably performant.

However, this won't yield the same benefits with `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, `REPLACE`, etc. as a genuine `UNIQUE` key.

Comment: I don't know if I've implemented it wrong but now I can't insert any values. What I did was that I ran your code in phpmyadmin on that table and now nothing happens when I insert something.

Comment: Got some strange error when I insert data inside phpmyadmin and will look into it in about 4 hours when I can access my computer again.

Comment: I get this error: #1436 - Thread stack overrun:  5768 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld -O thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.

Comment: @Oskwish: Sounds like you're either running a strange binary which was been compiled with a 128KiB stack, or else you're overriding the default with an explicit stack size of 128KiB (e.g. option file, command-line arguments, run-time settings?).  Default is normally 192KiB on a 32-bit architecture and 256KiB on a 64-bit architecture.

Comment: @eggyal So how do I fix that?

Comment: @Oskwish: Like the error said, "*Use 'mysqld -O thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.*"

Comment: Fixed it! I'm running this in XAMPP so I went in to the my.cnf and increased the thread_stack there. Though I would like to know where I would have written `mysqld -O thread_stack=#` to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select distinct a, b, c
from mytable
where c = 'x'
union all
select a, b, c
from mytable
where c <> 'x'
```